# Как сделать отзывчивость через js?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, Нужно, как я понимаю, отслеживать ширину экрана и в зависимости от нее использовать десктопный контейнер или мобилку.
ТЗ "Вёрстка должна быть отзывчивой (Responsive), минимальная ширина обёрнутого содержимого
630px, максимальная — 1270px. Проверяться будет именно изменение ширины обёрнутого
шаблона, а не изменение ширины окна браузера, т. е. если, например, ширина окна браузера
1920, а ширина обёрнутого содержимого будет ограничена 630-ю пикселями, то шаблон должен
соответствовать макету 630.psd."

Желательно максимально просто, я только начинаю с js... Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вам сразу готовый код со всеми комментариями и правками?)
P.s если вы начинаете JS, начните и с выполнения задачи, а там где будет не получатся, пишите сюда

Comment: В идеале да, код.. Если еще и поясните, как все это работает, то цены вам не будет! :)